# How to use object as parameteres in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a Typescript function, that takes two object parameteres **without previously knowing the keys of each object.**

I am trying to convert this function from JS to TS

```
function shallowEqual(object1, object2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);
  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let key of keys1) {
    if (object1[key] !== object2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do in below way that will check equality of objects

```
type TObject = {
  [key in string]?: string  | string[] | object;
}


function shallowEqual(object1: TObject, object2: TObject) {
  return JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shallowEqual(object1: any, object2: any): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2);
  }
```

OR

```
shallowEqual(object1: any, object2: any): boolean {    
    const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
    const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);
    if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (let key of keys1) {
      if (object1[key] !== object2[key]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```